# Running a pig script on top of YARN

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I have a pig script (with Perl streaming) running on top of pig 0.10.0 and MR v1. Now I tried to run the same pig script without change on top of YARN (2.1.0-beta) and pig 0.11.1 and I got the following error:

```
Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
```

I made sure that the YARN itself is working fine by running a few example MR programs and set HADOOP_HOME environment variable to point to YARN home directory. Is there any other thing I need to set up or test?

Comment: This error seems to be related with jar file classpath and I guess I am missing something related pig.

Comment: I have the same error when I ran Pig(version: 0.9.2) on Hadoop 2.4.0. I'm gonna install a newer version of Pig. I'll let you know if that helps...